# CSS getting applied to all files even though not imported

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I am dealing with 2 components:
`header.js` and `footer.js`.

I also have 2 css files:
`header.module.css` and `footer.module.css`. 
Both of them use different styling for the `a` tag.

I import the respective CSS files within each js file, but the `a` styling in `footer.module.css` seems to overtake the styling in `header.js` even though it wasn't imported.

Here is the code:

`header.js`

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import "../styles/header.module.css";

const ListLink = props => (
  <li style={{display: `inline-block`, marginRight: `1rem`, fontSize: '1.15rem', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
    <Link className="link" to={props.to}>{props.children}</Link>
  </li>
)
```

`footer.js`

```
import React from "react"
import "../styles/footer.module.css";

const FooterLink = props => (
  <li style={{ display: `inline-block`, marginRight: `1rem`, marginBottom:'0rem', fontSize: '1.05rem', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
    <a href={props.to} target="_blank">{props.children}</a>
  </li>
)
```

`header.module.css`

```
a {
    color: var(--textLink);
    text-shadow: var(--textShadow);
    transition:.2s;
    background-image: var(--bgimage);
}

a:hover {
    color: #da1e11;
    background-image: none;
}
```

`footer.module.css`

```
a{
    color: var(--textLink);
    text-shadow: var(--textShadow);
    transition:.2s;
    background-image: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: #da1e11;
    background-image: none;
}
```

The `background-image` property from `footer` overtakes the one specified in `header`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Gatsby's default `<Layout>`, it shares `<Header>` and `<Footer>` components so, both are loading each CSS in each page as you can see here:

```
  return (
    <>
      <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
      <div>
        <main>{children}</main>
        <Footer>
          © {new Date().getFullYear()}, Built with
          {` `}
          <a href="https://www.gatsbyjs.org">Gatsby</a>
        </Footer>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

The easiest solution is to wrap the each component in a class to make the CSS only available inside that class, something like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import "../styles/header.module.css";

    const ListLink = props => (
      <li className="list__item">
        <Link className="link" to={props.to}>{props.children}</Link>
      </li>
    )
```

*Note: you can even wrap the `<Link>` inside a `<div>` for example.*

I would suggest removing inline styles if you are using CSS modules to avoid mixing styles and improve readability.

The same applies for the `<Footer>` component.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) it's `import something from './something.module.css'` and then `<Component className={something.error}`

Comment: could you help me understand how I could modify the header.js file to make use of it? I am not making use of a class in this case.